# Add comma after value in Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I use below code,

```
    $i = 0; $comma = NULL;
foreach($messages->get_logged_agents_dep(60) as $val_dep)
{
    echo $department_id = $val_dep['department_id'].$comma;
}
```

I want to put comma (,) end of department_id (as I mentioned in $comma variable)
but last value should not put comma(,), because of I want to put above values in to SELECT * FROM tb_name WHERE IN (1,2,3) like this,
please help me to resolve this.
respect to your responds.

Thanks!

Comment: @sanojlawrence No, this is not anything like that. He's trying to print commas, not match values in a comma-separated column.

Comment: Hi,
Why can't we loop $i ? and after max count we can put comma variable empty? else set comma for variable? is it possible?

Comment: Instead of adding the comma as appending to item in sequence, add comma's only for additional items to the sequence

Answer (score 5):

Try this :-

```
foreach($messages->get_logged_agents_dep(60) as $val_dep)
{
    $department_id[] = $val_dep['department_id'];
}

echo $department_val =  implode(",",$department_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `rtrim()`

```
$department_id  = '';
foreach($messages->get_logged_agents_dep(60) as $val_dep) {
    $department_id .= $val_dep['department_id'].',';
}
rtrim($department_id,','); // to trim last comma
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to add the comma on the additional member of the sequence, not with.

```
$i = 0; 
$comma = ',';
foreach(...)
{
   echo ($i++>0)? $comma:'';
   echo $department_id = $val_dep['department_id'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use implode().  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
$i = 0; $arrIds = array();
foreach($messages->get_logged_agents_dep(60) as $val_dep)
{
    $arrIds[] = $val_dep['department_id'];
}
echo implode(',', $arrIds);
```

Comment: I think you meant "implode" function.